# Does Updating an Android Library cause Error in my Code?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-library

I was using 
`implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha05'`
library to render the Material Components but then I updated the library to 
`implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.2.0-alpha03'`
and everything bad happened. I was confused for an hour, asking myself where did I do wrong?

This was the error I had to experience:

Before Updating:

[This is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxPGr.png)

After Updating:

[This is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaxb5.png)

Is something wrong with my code or is it the Updated Library's fault.

This is the code in XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/DescriptionLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="top"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/DescriptionHint"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/BoxColor"
                app:hintTextColor="@color/BoxColor">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/DescriptionEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:drawingCacheQuality="auto"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|text|textAutoComplete"
                    android:minLines="3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

After Updating to latest Library this `android:gravity="top"` code for my EditText inside the TextInputLayout does not work.

And Also this wasn't the only place this has happened. Should I update the library or not? Can someone help me with this decision? By not updating a library, will my application not work properly?

I am sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Hi! Do you solved this problem?

Comment: I reverted to the previous version of Material Library

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by adding dense property in style.
Apply this style to your TextInputLayout.

style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"

[Refer to this link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

Comment: I cannot get the box in 29 Api but the box is there for almost all the Api's before it. Also the code ```android:gravity="top"``` does not work

Comment: This problem happened only after I updated the library to *1.2.0-alpha03*

Comment: Ok the Box is there but the code ```android:gravity="top"``` does not work

Comment: Did you try using padding instead of gravity?

Comment: I tried using padding but padding gives me different results on different devices. I have reported this to the material library developers. I hope they fix this in their next update.